# How to change the location of .cache in conda?

Tags: linux, server, anaconda, conda

I installed the latest version of Anaconda on my Linux server.

However, almost all the datasets and model weights are stored in the .cache file. How can I change the location of .cache file.

Here is what I have tried:

1. I checked the conda config by typing `conda config --show`

```
envs_dirs:
  - /nethome/usrname/.conda/envs
  - /opt/conda/envs

pkgs_dirs:
  - /opt/conda/pkgs
  - /nethome/usrname/.conda/pkgs
```

I wish I could store the `.cache` at `- /opt/conda/pkgs`. So I try to find the `.condarc` file but I did not find it.

What could I do to change the `.cache` file?

Comment: This has nothing do to with conda/anaconda, but is specific to whatever package you are using that utilizes these datasets. Are we talking about pytorch/tensorflow or something else here? Are these datasets and weights that came with any of these modules or are they something that you ahve generated?